# How I can select a specific AD in IAM menu

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

When I select an IAM menu (Identity + Acces Management) I see a list of user accounts extracted from my Azure AD

But I have several AD.From what criteria Azure select an AD rather another one?

Comment: When we add the users to the Azure AD, we can add the users from other tenants. And all the users will be listed in the tenant.

Comment: yes but I just see user account from the main AD. how is it possible to see all other id in the subscription

Answer (score 0):

Hi assuming your question is that you have multiple Azure Active Directories, rather than multiple on-prem ADs that you need to sync - then via the preview management blades in the new portal can you change which Direcotry they list via the icon on the top right which shows your logged in user.  From there simply select the Directory you wish to manage.

Answer (score 0):

It is only able to grant the access to the users in the Azure Active Directory which the Azure subscription trust. It is not able to switch the Azure Active Directory to grant the access.

*Each Azure subscription is associated with one Azure Active Directory (AD) directory. Users, groups, and applications from that directory can manage resources in the Azure subscription. Assign these access rights using the Azure portal, Azure command-line tools, and Azure Management APIs.
Grant access by assigning the appropriate RBAC role to users, groups, and applications at a certain scope. The scope of a role assignment can be a subscription, a resource group, or a single resource. A role assigned at a parent scope also grants access to the children contained within it. For example, a user with access to a resource group can manage all the resources it contains, like websites, virtual machines, and subnets.*
[image]

*The RBAC role that you assign dictates what resources the user, group, or application can manage within that scope.*

Here are some helpful articles about Role-based access control and Azure subscription:

[How Azure subscriptions are associated with Azure Active Directory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory/#accounts-that-you-can-use-to-sign-in)

[Get started with access management in the Azure portal](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-what-is/)

[Use role assignments to manage access to your Azure subscription resources](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-configure/)